# How to graph a hyperboloid of a leaf with intersections using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to plot `S1: -(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2=1`, `x=1` and `z=0` and their intersections using `tikzpicture` environment:

[image: Graph]

Using [this post about the equation of the hyperboloid of a leaf](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiperboloide#Ecuaci%C3%B3n_param%C3%A9trica) I end up with two type of equations.

Let `x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - z^2/c^2 = 1`.

- Parametric equation:

  - `x=a*cosh(u)*cos(v)`
  - `y=b*cosh(u)*sin(v)`
  - `z=c*sinh(u)`

    - for any real `u`
    - for `0º <= v <= 360º`
- Non-Hyperbolic equation:

  - `x=a*sqrt(1+u*u)*cos(v)`
  - `y=b*sqrt(1+u*u)*sin(v)`
  - `z=c*u`

    - for any real `u`
    - for `0º <= v <= 360º`

In our case, the first surface is `a=b=c=1`, but the `-` sign is in `x`-term, not `z`, so this is my first problem; I do not know how to change the order. Also note that `S1` is moved **one** unit on the `x`-axis.

The other plots are `x=1` and `z=0`.

Also, if possible, I would like to draw the intersections of these surfaces, i.e. there are two:

- Intersection of `S1` and `y^2+z^2=1` gives the orange curve,
- Intersection of `S1` and `z=0` gives the green curve.

Also I think the view is `view={135}{25}` but you can propose other good view!

*(Very)* basic MWE (I do not know why `S1` is of `z`-axis when it should be `x`-axis ???):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
        axis lines = center,
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        zlabel = $z$,
        legend style={cells={align=left}},
        legend cell align={left},
        view={135}{25},
        clip=false
        ]
        \addplot3[surf, mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples = 71,samples y=41,variable = \u,variable y = \v,domain =-360:360] ({(1+u*u)^(1/2)*cos(v)+1},{sqrt(1+u*u)*sin(v)},{u});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Hyperboloid of a leaf]

Please note the imperfection from `z<=0`: [image: Imperfections]

Thanks!

Comment: Some solutions that come to my mind: for the imperfections use `domain=-360-something:360-something` and for the `x`-axis just flip `z` parametric equation and `x` parametric equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this? (I think that the strange effect came from the domain `-360:360`. If you want to have more of a 3d feel, you need to decompose the hyperboloid anyway in pieces. This also fixes the domain problem. I also respond to Raaja, whom I'd like to thank for the nice suggestion to add some (fake) shading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={cm}{color(0)=(red) color(1)=(red!90)
color(3)=(red!80) color(4)=(red!70) color(5)=(red!10)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
        axis lines = middle,
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        zlabel = $z$,
        legend style={cells={align=left}},
        legend cell align={left},
        view={135}{25},
        clip=false,
        point meta={z-abs(0.2*x+y)}
        ]
        % lower back part
        \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,opacity=0.7,
        samples=71,samples y=41,domain y=-180:00,domain=-4:1]
        ({x},{sqrt(1+x*x)*cos(y)},{sqrt(1+x*x)*sin(y)});
        \addplot3[ultra thick,color=green,samples=71,samples y=1,
        domain=-180:00] ({1},{sqrt(1+1)*cos(x)},{sqrt(1+1)*sin(x)});
        % horizontal plane: back
        \fill[cyan,opacity=0.4] (1,5,0) -- (1,-5,0) -- (-4.5,-5,0) 
        -- (-4.5,5,0);
        %\addplot3[surf,cyan,domain=-4.5:1,domain y=-5:5,opacity=0.5] {0};
        % vertical plane: lower part
        \fill[cyan,opacity=0.4] (1,5,0) -- (1,-5,0) -- (1,-5,-5) 
        -- (1,5,-5);
        %\addplot3[surf,cyan,domain=-4.5:0,domain y=-5:5,opacity=0.5] ({1},{y},{x});
        % lower front part
        \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,
        shader=interp,opacity=0.7,samples=71,samples y=41,domain y=-180:00,
        domain=1:4] ({x},{sqrt(1+x*x)*cos(y)},{sqrt(1+x*x)*sin(y)});
        % horizontal plane: front
        \fill[cyan,opacity=0.4] (1,5,0) -- (1,-5,0) -- (5,-5,0) 
        -- (5,5,0);
        %\addplot3[surf,cyan,domain=1:4.5,domain y=-5:5,opacity=0.5] {0};
        % upper back part
        \addplot3[ultra thick,color=orange,samples=71,samples y=1,
        domain=-4:4]        ({x},{sqrt(1+x*x)},{0});
        \addplot3[ultra thick,color=orange,samples=71,samples y=1,
        domain=-4:4]        ({x},{-sqrt(1+x*x)},{0});
        \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,
        shader=interp,opacity=0.7,samples=71,samples y=41,domain y=0:180,
        domain=-4:1]
        ({x},{sqrt(1+x*x)*cos(y)},{sqrt(1+x*x)*sin(y)});
        % vertical plane: upper part
        \fill[cyan,opacity=0.4] (1,5,0) -- (1,-5,0) -- (1,-5,5) 
        -- (1,5,5);
        \addplot3[ultra thick,color=green,samples=71,samples y=1,
        domain=0:180] ({1},{sqrt(1+1)*cos(x)},{sqrt(1+1)*sin(x)});
        %\addplot3[surf,cyan,domain=0:4.5,domain y=-5:5,opacity=0.5] ({1},{y},{x});
        % upper front part
        \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,
        shader=interp,opacity=0.7,samples=71,samples y=41,domain y=0:180,
        domain=1:4] ({x},{sqrt(1+x*x)*cos(y)},{sqrt(1+x*x)*sin(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see some shadowing effects in the extremum locations in the OP's example which I miss here (But still a +1 from me).

Comment: That's an excellent good start. Did you "delete" the `y varies` effect to show better the graph? Also, I would like to graph the two intesections for then add a legend to  every plot.

Comment: @manooooh `mesh/ordering=y varies,` is still in, isn't it? And what do you mean by intersections?

Comment: @Raaja Thanks! I added one possibility to add some shading. Clearly, there are more sophisticated options. This is just my first guess for an appropriate `point meta`.

Comment: Y es I know that `y varies` is there but I mean that the plots don't have the colors from blue to red. By intersection I mean plot the two curves: a circle (in  orange) and equilateral hyperbola (in  green).

Comment: @marmot Super!!

Comment: @marmot Super.....man!!! +1 :-)